# gitignore not working in spite of removing the files from the cache

Tags: git

I have the following files listed in my `.gitignore`file, for simplicity sake we'll focus on just one:

```
latin/files/lasla_db.pkl
```

That file was never added to my github repository but maybe someone how it got added into the cache or something like that so I ran:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:latin bobsmith$ git rm --cached latin/files/lasla_db2.pkl
rm latin/files/lasla_db2.pkl
```

I then ran the following commands:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:latin bobsmith$ git add .
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:latin bobsmith$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
    deleted:    latin/files/lasla_db.pkl
```

I then ran the following:

```
Admins-MacBook-Pro-4:latin bobsmith$ git commit -m 'a'
[master 81b1e23] a
 12 files changed, 9 deletions(-)
 delete mode 100644 latin/files/lasla_db.pkl
```

I then ran

```
git push -u origin master
```

I got two error messages related to large files which I'm not worried about because once I ignore the offending files I assume the problem will go away:

```
remote: error: Trace: a46785362c02dd013da2eba7570e06c706a9f31357257ef6957b9f39b86c2efe
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
```

But one I do understand but don't understand why I'm getting it since I'm ignoring that file:

```
remote: error: File latin/files/lasla_db.pkl is 217.16 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

Comment: Seems the file has already been tracked by git. (You are 2 commits ahead of remote). You'll probably have to edit/rebase/cherry-pick those commits and clean them up. What does `git log --stat -- latin/files/lasla_db.pkl` give you?

Comment: The commits were never added to github.  Can I just delete those commits rather than deleting stuff one by one which will be very hard for me anyway since I'm not very good with Git?

Comment: I posted instructions for "deleting" those commits in an answer. If anything is unclear, let me know :)

Comment: [Jay's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72572845/1256452) is fine and obviously worked for you, but for this one particular case, you could also use `git rebase -i` and use squash or fixup to remove the big file from the mistaken commit. Something to keep in mind for the future; `rebase -i` is a major power tool (I like to think of it as the CNC machine in the machine shop).

Comment: cool, thanks, i'll keep that in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the file seems to have been tracked since the second last (non-pushed) commit, we'll reset the local branch to an older commit (the one its on origin).

1. Define a new local branch or tag based on current state, that way we can find/use those discarded commits later:

   `git branch before_reset`
2. Also make sure we don't lose any changes that weren't checked in yet (if any):

   `git stash save -u`
   (If it says that changes were found/saved, you can restore those changes later with `git stash apply`
3. Reset the local branch to origin:

   `git reset HEAD@{upstream}`
4. Now you can reapply your changes cleanly.
   The first step you probably want to do is get the version of `.gitignore` as it was before the reset:

   `git checkout before_reset -- .gitignore`

---

How to avoid this situation in future:

When committing I recommend **against** using `-m` to specify the commit message.
If you don't use this option, the editor will open and give you a chance to review your changes before finishing the commit.
If you notice anything wrong with the commit (e.g. files being added that should not be added), save the file without any commit message and the commit will be aborted.

---

Explanation regarding: "gitignore not working"

gitignore causes git commands to ignore files that are **currently** not tracked by git.

However if you already have 2 commits in your history, e.g.

commit 1: adds file
commit 2: deletes file

then gitignore cannot magically make the file disappear from the history. (Because commit contents are basically set in stone)

It will only prevent the file from being added again.

If you try to push your local branch, commit 1 and commit 2 are part of the history. And because they contain the file (once as add, once as delete) you got the size error.

Comment: As an aside to an otherwise fine answer: Although I also avoid `-m` for the most part, rather than "avoid -m" as a sort of blanket way to check things, I recommend running `git status`, inspecting its output carefully, and running `git diff --cached`.

Comment: Indeed, good advice :) Checking manually before committing is better (because you can see the diffs and stats) and more comfortable. That's actually what I always do myself. However, avoiding `-m` does help a lot in case the user tends to forget to manually check before committing. And apparently many people rush and forget to check. Avoiding `-m` is basically just an additional safety net. (But I know people who also rush that step and don't read what the editor says...)